# select2.js and Bootstrap validator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out why select2.js and Bootstrap validator are not working.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/jEADR/1720/)**

```
$('form.validate-form').validator({
    disable: false
});

$(".mySelect").select2();

$( "select.mySelect" ).each(function() {
    $(this).validator();
    $(this).get(0).setCustomValidity('Please select at least one item in the list.');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what's not working? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: It should show an error message if you leave the select field in blank.

Answer (score 0):

You must add rules for the form and id to select2 to validate it

> id="mySelect"

form html and scripts

```
<form class="validate-form" data-toggle="validator"> 
   <label class="required">Geographic market experience </label>
   <select id="mySelect" multiple="true" class="mySelect">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
      <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
      <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form.validate-form").validate({
  rules: {
      mySelect: "required"
  },
  messages: {
      mySelect: "Please select your region"
  }
});
</script>
```